# KeyError accessing data in nested dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have the following Python script:

```
lista_contatos = {
    "1": {"nome": "Paul", "cel": "+9999999999", "cidade": "SP", "id_cidade": "449139"},
    "2": {"nome": "Junior", "cel": "+999999999", "cidade": "SP", "id_cidade": "449139"}

}
n = len(lista_contatos)
i = int
i = 1
print(n)

while i <= n:
    print(i)
    print(lista_contatos[i]['nome'])
    print(lista_contatos[i]['cel'])
    i = i + 1
```

The problem that I'm facing is that I need to print all the data from each key before proceeding to the second array print.

The problem is when I add the counter `i` as a print key, I'm getting an error.

Any help how to solve this?

Comment: Do you understand that this is a dictionary? Your `i` value is integer, so you should not expect it to match with a string key.

Comment: @ggorlen after change "1": ["nome": "Paul", "cel": "+9999999999", "cidade": "SP", "id_cidade": "449139"], i'm getting SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: `for key, value in lista_contatos.items():`

Comment: use lista_contatos[str(i)]['nome'] to access the elements or make the keys as integer

Comment: "1" is not equal to 1

Comment: you can't use `[]` to change dictionary into list - you would have to keep only values without keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This data structure doesn't make much sense. If your keys are only sequential numbers and you plan to iterate over the elements, then a dictionary is the wrong tool. [Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=lists#list) (or [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=lists#tuples), if immutability is desired) were invented for exactly your intended purpose, and walking contiguous chunks of memory is far more efficient and semantically appropriate than hashing.

Additionally, `for` loops are the correct construction for walking a list, not `while` loops, which are more appropriate when the stopping condition is something other than a counter.

```
lista_contatos = [
    {"nome": "Paul", "cel": "+9999999999", "cidade": "SP", "id_cidade": "449139"},
    {"nome": "Junior", "cel": "+999999999", "cidade": "SP", "id_cidade": "449139"}
]

for elem in lista_contatos:
    print(elem['nome'], elem['cel'])
```

As for your original problem, since integers are illegal values for dict keys, `{"1": "foo"}[1]` produces your `KeyError`. You'd need to convert the `i` to a string,

```
lista_contatos[str(i)]['cel']
#              ^^^^^^
```

This should feel like jumping through a hoop and is a red flag that something has gone wrong with the choice of data structure.

That's not to say that looping over dictionaries isn't ever good, but the way it works is by turning the dictionary into a [view object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) using `some_dict.items()`, `some_dict.keys()` or `some_dict.values()`. If you're using Python < 3.6, ordering is not guaranteed (use a `collections.OrderedDict`). A counter like `i` would not enter the picture in any case.

The intent with `i = int` is probably to declare a type. But this aliases `int`, which is a builtin type used for casting, to the variable `i`. You don't need to declare types in Python like this; just write `i = 1` and Python knows it's an integer automatically:

```
>>> i = 1      
>>> type(i)    
<class 'int'>
```

---

When to actually use a dictionary? The answer is whenever you need fast lookups for related items on a key-value pair basis where the key is some unique, hashable identifier other than a sequential integer from `0..n`. Imagine an inventory of products, each with some arbitrary UPC or SKU number as the key, and the rest of the product data as a dict of properties.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to do DFS printing.

```
lista_contatos = {"1": {"nome": "Paul", "cel": "+9999999999", "cidade": "SP", "id_cidade": "449139"},
                "2": {"nome": "Junior", "cel": "+999999999", "cidade": "SP", "id_cidade": "449139"}}

def printDict(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        print('key: ', k)
        if type(v) is dict:
            printDict(v)
        else:
            print('value: ', v)
printDict(lista_contatos)
```

result:

```
key:  2
key:  id_cidade
value:  449139
key:  cidade
value:  SP
key:  nome
value:  Junior
key:  cel
value:  +999999999
key:  1
key:  id_cidade
value:  449139
key:  cidade
value:  SP
key:  nome
value:  Paul
key:  cel
value:  +9999999999
```

Comment: it considers nested documents, not sure whether you need this